# How to profile if in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization, profiling

Is there a tool for know how many time my if it's true and how many time it is false

for exemple:

```
if (vector.size() == 1)
    return;
do_something();
```

How to know how many time this if is true?

Comment: Add a count to each branch?

Comment: TotalCount = TrueCount + FalseCount

Comment: Questions asking to recommend a tool are off topic in SO.  There are many such tools (and you can also use in-line code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code is inside a function, you can use static variable :

```
void function(){

    static int cptTrue;
    static int cptFalse;

    if (vector.size() == 1){
        cptTrue++;
        return;
    }
    cptFalse++;
    do_something();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows there is a tool which shows you how frequently a function is called. A tree is constructed from libraries to functions and lines which shows cpu usage percentages. But if you want to know exactly how many times a line is called, the best way is manually counting them as **baddger964** suggested.

[very sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/)

Comment: There are plenty of code coverage tools which will tell you how many times each line is executed (and even whether a branch is taken or not).